# filtring boolean values inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array like this :

```
 const appoint =[
  { a: "asas",
    b:{au: false, h:false,l:true}
  },
  { a: "avd",
    b:{au: true, h:false,l:true}
  },
  { a: "as", b:{au: true, h:false,l:false}
  }];
```

When I access  b , I want to filter the falsy values, so far I'm not successful doing it with a serie of map() like this :

```
const result = appoint.map(elem => elem.b.)
const finalresult = result.map(
         item =>item.filter(
              (item, value)=> item[value] === false )
          )
```

Comment: `elem.b.` <-- is the last point a typo?... Anyway, you can't apply `filter` on an object. What is the expected output format?

Comment: how the expected output will look like?

Comment: To elaborate, you want to remove any properties that have `false` as value, from the related objects? Or create a new object, that has all properties, except for the ones with `false` as value? As a note, imho, the name `finalresult` is not good, if the previous one is not at least `intermediateresult`. Next, you'll add a `finalfinalresult` or an `endresult`, and readability only goes downhill here.

Comment: This issue is that you are mapping an array then filtering an object, and objects cannot be filtered

Comment: the outcome should be this: [l,l,au]

Comment: You meant `['l','l','au']`? If so, why the duplicate `l`? you can't elaborate that element further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use `map` to get an new array which contains only `b`, then use `reduce` and inside reduce callback use `for..in` to iterate the object and get the keys which is true

```js
const appoint = [{
    a: "asas",
    b: {
      au: false,
      h: false,
      l: true
    }
  },
  {
    a: "avd",
    b: {
      au: true,
      h: false,
      l: true
    }
  },
  {
    a: "as",
    b: {
      au: true,
      h: false,
      l: false
    }
  }
];


let filtered = appoint.map(function(item) {
  return item.b;
}).reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  for (let keys in curr) {
    if (curr[keys]) {
      acc.push(keys)
    }
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

elem.b is an object, not an array, so you can't use filter on it. You could do something like this:

```
const bArray = appoint.map(elem => elem.b)
const finalresult = bArray.map(b => {
  bKeys = Object.keys(b)
  const filtered = {}
  bKeys.forEach(key => {
    if (!b[key]) filtered[key] = false
  })
  return filtered
})
```

Comment: this is helpful, what about if I want filtred to be an array ?

Comment: An array of what? Key names that have a false value?
`const filtered = []; bKeys.forEach(key => { if (!b[key]) filtered.push(key) })`

Comment: Or `const filtered = bKeys.filter(key => !b[key])`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `getKeysBy()` function that takes an object, and a predicate and returns the keys that pass the predicate check.

Now you can use `Array.flatMap()` with `getKeysBy()` to get an array of all the keys.

```js
const appoint = [{"a":"asas","b":{"au":false,"h":false,"l":true}},{"a":"avd","b":{"au":true,"h":false,"l":true}},{"a":"as","b":{"au":true,"h":false,"l":false}}]
  
const getKeysBy = (predicate, obj) => 
  Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([, v]) => predicate(v))
  .map(([k]) => k)
  
const result = appoint.flatMap(o => getKeysBy(v => v !== false, o.b))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
let array = [{
    a: "asas",
    b: {
        au: false,
        h: false,
        l: true
    }
}, {
    a: "avd",
    b: {
        au: true,
        h: false,
        l: true
    }
}, {
    a: "as",
    b: {
        au: true,
        h: false,
        l: false
    }
}, {
    a: "ab",
    b: {
        au: false,
        h: false,
        l: false
    }
}]

let output = array.filter((element) => {
    let keys = Object.keys(element.b)
    element.b = keys.filter((key) => {
        if (element.b[key]) {
            return key
        }
    })
    if (!Object.keys(element.b).length) {
        element.b = []
    }
    return element;
})
console.log(output)
```

This will give you

```
[
    {
        "a": "asas",
        "b": [
            "l"
        ]
    },
    {
        "a": "avd",
        "b": [
            "au",
            "l"
        ]
    },
    {
        "a": "as",
        "b": [
            "au"
        ]
    },
    {
        "a": "ab",
        "b": []
    }
]
```

I assume you might need an empty array if none of the values are true.